# wpf C# retrieving accent color windows 10

Tags: c#, wpf, colors

Yes, WPF.

How to retrieve accent color that the user has chosen in Windows settings into a desktop WPF application?

for example for a Button?

Answer (score 13):

I'm not sure which version of .Net you're using, but if you're using 4.5 or higher, you can use the [SystemParameters](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.systemparameters(v=vs.110).aspx) class. I think the property you more than likely are after is the [WindowsGlassBrush](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.systemparameters.windowglassbrush(v=vs.110).aspx).

```
this.Background = SystemParameters.WindowGlassBrush;
```

Note though, that the properties in this class are marked with [SecurityCriticalAttribute](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.security.securitycriticalattribute(v=vs.110).aspx), so you will more than likely need full trust to access them.

Comment: This works! I wonder what this does when this runs on an older version of Windows that didn't have accent colors like Windows 10.

Comment: This will not get the correct colour if "Automatically pick an accent color from my background" is enabled.

Comment: This works in Windows 11 too.

Answer (score 10):

I wanted the XAML version of Richard Preziosi answer, that would be :

```
BorderBrush="{Binding Source={x:Static SystemParameters.WindowGlassBrush}}"
```

Comment: The following works in Windows 11:
`<Setter Property="Foreground" Value="{x:Static SystemParameters.WindowGlassBrush}"/>`